# Is there a difference between the two sentences?

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs

> -The train could leave Boston.
>
> -The train would leave Boston.

Is there a difference? Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 0):

I think yes! The difference in meaning lies in the modal verbs used, 'could' and 'would'. Yet I feel that we need more context to better understand the actual meaning of the two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

"Could" is generally about capability
"Would" is generally about possibility.

The difference in those two sentences would be:

**"The train could leave Boston"**: the train is capable of leaving Boston, but whether it *will* or not is uncertain. The sentence simply says that it can, nothing more.

**"The train would leave Boston"**: the train *can and will* leave Boston, it's simply a matter of *when*.

As you can see, their meanings are slightly different, and are not interchangeable